# DataFrame: Sort values of a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe like below

```
A        B
===========================
AA     1,3,5,2,20,11
BB     9,44,2,33,1,21
```

Is there a way to sort the values in column "B" as below

```
A        B
===========================
AA     1,2,3,5,11,20
BB     1,2,9,21,33,44
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function, first convert to integers after `split`, sorted and last convert back to strings for `join`:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(','))))))
#alternative
#df["B"] = [','.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(','))))) for x in df["B"]]
print (df)
    A               B
0  AA   1,2,3,5,11,20
1  BB  1,2,9,21,33,44
```

Alternative solutions:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(str(z) for z in sorted(int(y) for y in x.split(',')))
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(f)

df["B"] = [','.join(str(z) for z in sorted(int(y) for y in x.split(','))) for x in df["B"]]
```